# Axis labels with matplotlib or seaborn xticks - inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My goal is to receive a list of the actual labels printed on a matplotlib plot (x and y / abscissa and ordinate labels).
However, I noticed some inconsistent behavior of seaborn / matplotlib while doing so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from numpy.random import rand, randint, normal

s0 = normal(0,.5,100)
s1 = normal(0,1,100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':s0, 'b':s1})

# ###
# # prints wrong x axis xtick labels:
# (not providing the bounds)
g = sns.regplot(x = 'a', y = 'b', data = df)

# (have to render before getting the list of xtick labels)
g.figure.canvas.draw()
l = plt.xticks()
print([x.get_text() for x in l[1]])
plt.show()


###
# prints correct x axis xtick labels:
g = sns.regplot(x = 'a', y = 'b', data = df)

# # (due to not providing the bounds)
plt.xlim(0,1)

# # (have to render before getting the list of xtick labels)
g.figure.canvas.draw()
text_labels = plt.xticks()[1]
print([x.get_text() for x in text_labels])
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image: output]

As you may see, in the first case (not providing an xlim() statement) the first and last labels are not included in the image. If this were *always* the case, I could simply remove them.  However, this is not always the case, as when the numbers land on the interval they are printed to the image (see next example).

Is there a way to simply get these labels from the image in a more predictable manner?

Comment: Matplotlib may create labels, even if they are not shown on the plot. This usually shouldn't bother the user though. Can you tell *why* you need that list of labels, such that we don't run into an xyproblem here.

Comment: I'm making a bunch of these graphs to test OCR on these images, so I need the labels and images to match.

Comment: I suppose to test some OCR you can just use the solution with `plt.xlim` present in the code.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'll do. I just thought there was a better function to gather the actual labels on the axes.